# Excel 2010 having UserForm select the correct row to edit

Tags: excel-2010, userform

I have set up a UserForm with a drop-down that is used to select the name of the person whose data I want to edit. It selects the right person and populates the UserForm with their data.

*HOWEVER*

No matter which row/record I select, it copies the data to the first row and any edits I make end up there. Meanwhile, the 'original' record remains where it is thereby creating a duplicate record.

My UserForm drop-down list is called 'cmbItemName'. Here is the subroutine I have set up for when the name changes:

```
Private Sub cmbItemName_Change()

vrange = "FirstField"

Skill.Text = Application.VLookup(cmbItemName.Value, Sheets("Enrolled").Range(vrange), 12, True)
```

(... there are several more lines, one for each column of data. They all look like the above example).

"FirstField" is a named range that looks like this: `=OFFSET(Enrolled!$A$3,0,0,COUNTA(Enrolled!A:A)-0,29)`. This is used to select the range of names to be searched.

My question is: how do I tell the UserForm to make the edits on the row where the data is originally found? If the searched name is found on row 63, make the edits on row 63.

Help?

**EDIT:**

I have a separate sub to change each item:

```
Private Sub skill_Change()
Range("L" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
ActiveCell.Value = Skill.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: I dont see anywhere in the code you provided where you are writting to a cell/row..... that may be beneficial since you are asking why its writing to the first row each time.

Comment: My apologies. See my edit above.

Comment: from what I can see, when you call application vlookup you need to get the address of the cell, assuming this is the row you want to edit, then use the address to set the skill text.  You can then pass that address to the skill_Change routine and use it to activate that specific row's cells.  As it sits now whatever cell is the active cell is where you are making edits.

Comment: Given what you see of my code, what needs to be changed or added?

Comment: are you tied to the vlookup function as this would need to change to an index match function in order to get the cell address.  otherwise we get the value then loop backk through the range to get the address.

Comment: No, I am not tied to the vlookup function. This was something I found online that seemed to work. I am open to suggestions.